# How to properly control the position of a Cloned element when dragging it elsewhere

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

The code is intended to Drag/Drop a "Person" into a timeslot of a "Room", thus creating a "Reservation".  The cloning of the person into the room works as expected, but later dragging that cloned element (now a "Reservation"), results in very weird positioning, and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass("person")) {
        var theItem = $(ui.draggable).clone();
        theItem.removeClass('person');
        theItem.addClass('rsvd');
    }else{
        var theItem = $(ui.draggable);
        // This Prevents wacky positioning
        theItem.removeAttr('style');    
    }
    theItem.draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
    });
    $(this).append(theItem);
}
```

The bare-bones code is at http://jsfiddle.net/gdpodesta/fD48E/, and you can see that after dragging either of the two *purple* names into a timeslot, the resulting *red* element cannot be positioned properly in another timeslot.

I've found that by removing the `style` attribute during the `drop` event, the problem goes away, but this doesn't seem like the "right" way of doing it....there's much more work to be done with this, and I don't want to go down a long path to find that this approach creates other problems - what am I missing to do it the right way?

P.S.  *I realize that using a table isn't "correct", but this allows me to clearly and easily control unrelated positioning, and leaves the CSS free to position according to the jquery events.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [Rahul Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2833516/rahul-gupta) pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24485252/2333214), the problem is with the clones having inline style.

*Why?*

Because for `.rsvd` you're using the original item for dragging, so all the positioning will be applied to the item being dragged and later you're appending a clone of the item along with  the positioning.

*Why this is not happening initially for `.person`?*

Because you're using a `clone` as `helper`, so all the positioning wil be applied to the helper, you're cloning the original item which is untouched (*no positioning is applied to it*).

for fixing the issue, you can simply use a `clone` as `helper` while initializing it (`.rsvd`) as draggable inside the `drop` function

```
theItem.draggable({
            helper: 'clone',
            revert: "invalid",
        });
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fD48E/5/)

*Side note: the draggable initialization you're doing for `.rsvd` in `$(document).ready()` is useless since there are no matching elements at that time*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the cloned elements has `style=position: relative;` which is causing the improper placement. So instead of removing the whole `style` attribute, you have to just set the value to attribute `position` to `''`. Like this:

```
...
.....
// This Prevents wacky positioning
theItem.css('position',''); //removed the previous code  theItem.removeAttr('style'); 
.....
....
```

Comment: I guess that's the problem I'm trying to understand - that CSS, along with TOP, and LEFT are being added by jQuery when it's originally cloned, and works in the initial drop spot, but not later, when it's dragged.